# How to make checkbox checked on field update

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I am making a form with 10 fields with 10 checkboxes. On updating the field i want relevant checkbox to be checked. I can make it work by writing 10 different ON change function but i am looking for a smart way to achieve it instead of writing 10 different ON change functions for respective fields.

```
<input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-1"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
<label class="form-label">Field 1</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-2"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
<label class="form-label">Field 2</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-3"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
<label class="form-label">Field 3</label>

$('#field-1').bind('change', () => {
    $('#checkbox-1').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#field-2').bind('change', () => {
    $('#checkbox-2').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#field-3').bind('change', () => {
    $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your iinput field and checkbox in a div and then add the logic of checking your checkbox to those wrappers.

```js
$('.checked-input').find('input[type=text]').on('change', function(){
 $(this).closest('.checked-input').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checked-input">
   <input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
   <input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox"/>
</div>

<div class="checked-input">
   <input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
   <input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [starts-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to find all your fields and bind `input` handlers. Then when you are able to handle it, you have to find appropriate `checkbox` and check it:

```js
$('input[name^="field-"]').on('input', function(){
 let fieldId = $(this).attr('name').slice(-1);
 $('#checkbox-'+fieldId).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-1"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
<label class="form-label">Field 1</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-2"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
<label class="form-label">Field 2</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox-3"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
<label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group all input which contain `field` in their `id` and use the number `id` to check corresponding checkbox:

```js
$('input[id*=field]').on('change', function() {
  $('#checkbox-' + $(this).prop("id").split('-')[1]).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-1"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
<label class="form-label">Field 1</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-2"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
<label class="form-label">Field 2</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-3"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
<label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could tell the input which checkbox to target using a data poperty.  I also put an alternate to only check if not empty OR an alternate to find the prior sibling of each.

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function(event) {
  let checkpair = $(this).data('targetpair');
  $(checkpair).prop('checked', true);
  // alternate only if not empty:
  //$(checkpair).prop('checked', $(this).val().trim().length);
});

/* alternate that finds the immediate checkbox sibling
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function(event) {
 $(this).prevAll('input[type=checkbox]').first().prop('checked', true);
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-1"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-1" data-targetpair="#checkbox-1" name="field-1">
<label class="form-label">Field 1</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-2"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-2" data-targetpair="#checkbox-2" name="field-2">
<label class="form-label">Field 2</label>

<input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox-3"></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="field-3" data-targetpair="#checkbox-3" name="field-3">
<label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
```